# Python Numpy - 3-dimensional indices in 2-dimensional array without loop

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, broadcasting, n-dimensional

I want to construct an array `V1`, of shape `(n,p,q)` using an array of indices, `idx`, with the same shape, applied to an array `V0`, of shape `(p,q)`. The way to construct it with a loop is the following.

```
for i in range(n):
    V1[i,:,:] = V0[idx[i,:,:],range(q)]
```

In other words, the `idx[i,:,:]` array contains indices for the elements of the 1st dimension of `V0`. I apply it with the associated index of the 2nd dimension, captured in `range(q)`, to get the corresponding element along the fist dimension of the final array `V1`.

My question is the following: is there a way to construct `V1` without looping, by using broadcasting/indexing techniques?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
V1 = V0[idx, range(q)] #?
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np

# set up dummy data
n,p,q = 3,4,5
V1 = np.empty((n,p,q))
V0 = np.random.rand(p,q)
idx = np.random.randint(0,n,(n,p,q))

# original
V1_old = V1.copy()
for i in range(n):
    V1_old[i,:,:] = V0[idx[i,:,:],range(q)]

# new
V1_new = V0[idx, range(q)]

# test
print(np.array_equal(V1_old, V1_new)) # True
```